# API base url not working in Reactjs login module

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working with Reactjs,I downloaded project from server and now trying to run this project,But right now i am unable to login( entered correct details) but problem is with "API URL",I checked in console,Api url for live server is `"https://xxxxxxxxxx.com/api/login/"` but in localhost console displaying like

```
host
    localhost:3001
filename
    /undefined/login/
```

So how can i make this working ?  Here is my current code in "src/utlis/api.js"

```
export const BASE_URL = `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_BASE_URL}`
axios.defaults.baseURL = BASE_URL
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a file named `.env` inside the project folder.

And write the following to this file.

```
REACT_APP_API_BASE_URL=https://xxxxxxxxxx.com/api/
```

For more detailed information, you can check the following.

- https://nodejs.dev/en/learn/how-to-read-environment-variables-from-nodejs/
- https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv

Comment: but why i use "live url" in localhost ? means how live url work in localhost ? (maybe site origin issue)

Comment: @Tomlanthom I can't say anything without seeing the source code.